# How to download client vpn exe file of azure virtual network

Tags: c#, azure, networking, virtual

I am building an app setting vpn point to site of azure

I created a virtual network
added gateway and uploaded certificate

now client vpn package of 64bit and 32bit are displayed on dashboard

I want to download them by code C# 
 anyone has any idea

please share with me some guide or links

thanks in advance
Quyen Pham

Comment: sorri anyone has any idea in here

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using the Service Management REST API, after authentication you just need to do a POST HTTP Request to

```
https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/networking/<virtual-network-name>/gateway/vpnclientpackage
```

With a payload like this:

```
<VpnClientParameters>
  <ProcessorArchitecture>architecture-of-processor</ProcessorArchitecture>
</VpnClientParameters>
```

Where valid values are AMD64 or X86, futhermore you must send a version header.

[More info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn205126.aspx)